# Typeorm / Nest.JS - Bad Performance when deployed

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, nestjs, typeorm

Hey I've got a question about typeorms / nestjs performance:

When i call the http route for this service on my computer I get a response in about
2-3 seconds which is okay (it's about 5,23MB of data) but if I deploy the service to
the Google App Engine it takes about 30 - 60 seconds.

```
@Injectable()
export class RegalService {
​
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Regal, 'kemware') private readonly regalRepository: Repository<Regal>
    ) { }
​
    relations = [
        'Faecher',
        'Faecher.Artikel',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Lieferanten',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Lieferanten.Lieferant',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Lieferanten.Staffelmengen',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Lieferanten.mengeneinheit',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Bilder',
        'Faecher.Artikel.Zeichnungen',
        'Faecher.Artikel.mengeneinheit'
    ];
​
    get(): Promise<Regal[]> {
        return this.regalRepository.find({relations: this.relations});
    }
​
}
```

[image: Deployed API]

[image: Local API]

I know that this is a big amount of data but the difference between my local computer and the deployed version shouldn't be that big.

If I execute the query typeorm is producing in MySQL Workbench it only takes 150ms.

I hope someone can help me with that problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the generated SQL?